# Copy Certificate from .pem file to another

Tags: openssl

I have a .PEM file containing the **CERTIFICATE** and **RSA PRIVATE KEY**.

I want to copy the certificate to another .PEM file and the RSA PRIVATE KEY to another.

**RSA PRIVATE KEY i'm using the following command and works perfectly:**

```
openssl rsa -in my_file.pem -out my_key.key -outform PEM
```

Now, what i want to do is instead of copy the PRIVATE KEY, copy the CERTIFICATE (BEGIN CERTIFICATE UNTIL END CERTIFICATE). What are the best approach here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly what you want is to have the exact same file but with a different name. If that is the case you don't need to copy anything just use 
the `mv` command. The `mv` command moves a file from one place to another if the second paramter is a directory(e.g /home) and renames it if it is a file (e.g. /path/file)

If you want to be safe:

```
cp my_file.pem copy.my_file.pem
cp my_key.key copy.my_key.key


mv my_file.pem  /path/to/new_file_name.pem
mv my_key.key /path/to/new_file_name.pem
```

Obviously you can place the /path of everything, but you mention you wanted to copy it to somewhere else.

Comment: Not. The file contains PRIVATE KEY and the CERTIFICATES. The Private Key is working fine. Now, i need to copy the first line "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" until the line "END CERTIFICATE".

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to just copy the file and edit it with a text editor to remove all the "PRIVATE KEY" lines.

If you're looking for an openssl command line solution like you have for your private key then you could do:

```
$ openssl x509 -in my_file.pem -out my_cert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's exactly what i'm doing. My main goal now is to turn this all automatic. Just enter the name of the file and copies the Certificate to a file, the Private Keys to another file.

Comment: So, don't you have all the info you need to do that now? Use `openssl rsa` for your private key (as per your original question), and `openssl x509` for the certificate - as per my answer.